# Firefox reports ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap when it accesses nodejs

Tags: node.js, firefox

node version:v0.12.02

firefox version: 40.0.4

I create a website through node with TLS, because of security ,I wanna use TLS V1.2 in my webapp.

According to the site  https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/tls.html

```html
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256, DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 and AES128-GCM-SHA256 are TLS v1.2 ciphers and used when Node.js is linked against OpenSSL 1.0.1 or newer, such as the bundled version of OpenSSL. Note that it is still possible for a TLS v1.2 client to negotiate a weaker cipher unless honorCipherOrder is enabled.
```

I use the cipher in order to only support TLs v1.2

```
var credentials = {
key: privateKey, 
cert:certificate,
ciphers:"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256"
};
```

There are no problems wen accessed by Chrome &IE,However, when use Firefox , the ‘ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap" was appeared.

Then I add a "HIGH" to the ciphers, likes this:

ciphers:"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH"

This solves the previous problem and FireFox's behavior is OK. 
But after add "HIGH" , the web browser with tls1.0,tls1.1 can access my website.
I am so confused by this problem. Any one can tell me the reason or how can I only use tls1.2 in nodejs? 
Thank you.